# React/MaterialUI - How can I edit my multiple-input to display a different placeholder other than those in my options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an inputfield/dropdown menu that takes in two JSON objects, `symbol` and `company`.

```
export default function SymbolInput() {

    const [data, setData] = useState({ companies: [] });

    const classes = useStyles();

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("https://app.url.io/").then((res) => {
            setData({ companies: res.data });
        });
    }, [setData]);
    

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Autocomplete
                multiple
                options={data.companies}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.symbol + ' | ' +  option.company}
                filterSelectedOptions
                renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="Companies"
                />
                )}
            />
        </div>
    );
```

How it looks like:

[image]

I'd like to keep the dropdown menu as is, and when a user selects or enters a field using the `textfield`, I want the company symbols only to appear as the placeholder, not symbol + company name.

So as an example, the placeholders for the above image would be `A AAPL ABBV ABMD`

How may I be able to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your sample code, it looks like `AutoComplete`'s prop `getOptionLabel` is the function that renders the label.

Right now it's

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.symbol + ' | ' +  option.company}
```

So to only show the symbol, it probably would just be

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.symbol}
```

EDIT:
It looks like `AutoComplete` also accepts a `renderOption` prop. Use both if you want the dropdown elements and the textfield to have different renders.

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.symbol + ' | ' +  option.company}
renderOption={(option) => option.symbol}
```

EDIT 2:
If you want custom behavior, you have to track the search text yourself and use the `filterOptions` prop and create your own search function. Here is a codesandbox of a functional example. You have to tailor it to your own needs.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4ibur?file=/demo.js

Comment: Hey @Andrew, thanks for the comment. So I'm actually looking to keep the dropdown: `{(option) => option.symbol + ' | ' +  option.company}` . I want the input in the select field, to only reflect `option.symbol`. If I use your code, then the options in the dropdown wont contain the company names as well (which I want).

Comment: by select field, I mean `<textfield>`

Comment: Thank you for finding that, so actually from testing out. I would have to add `{(option) => option.symbol + ' | ' +  option.company}` to `renderOption`. Followed by, `{(option) => option.symbol}` to `getOptionLabel`. We both had their functionality switched around. Making those changes get everything look nice. However, now when I search for terms, the dropdown menu does not search for `company` name, only the `symbol` is being used as a search parameter, even when the company name is displayed next to the dropdown.

Comment: @Dre Updated. You have to create your own filter function and render your own custom options